# How to efficiently update a package on debian beyond what is available from the repository?

Tags: linux, debian, package-management, packages

How to update a debian package beyond what is available with apt-get from the official repository of my version of Debian (9.13). For example Python3.0>Python3.7, or meson0.37.1-1>meson0.54. For some packages you can download the .deb package from a project's homepage but for projects with lots of dependencies manually installing each is both tedious and risky since you end up with partially installed packages.

Comment: Could upgrading Debian itself help (10, 11, or even Testing)? Have you checked if these programs have a repository you could add to your /etc/apt/sources.list (makes installs/updates easier than manual .deb's)? And/or have you considered if Snap, AppImage, or Flatpack packages could work for your specific programs/use cases? Perhaps Docker containers could be an option? Beyond compiling from source yourself (hardly efficient), these are the best options I can think of.

Comment: I was able to install the application with Flatpack but it's a workaround. I want to know what the repository names to add to /etc/apt/sources.list.d are for installing after EOL. I should upgrade Debian anyway.